# Is not mentioning business environment equal to off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[SSH server accepts connection and immediately disconnects](https://serverfault.com/questions/674213/ssh-server-accepts-connection-and-immediately-disconnects)

In this question, I'm wondering if the server is been attacked. I failed to mention if the server is for my company.

The question is closed as off-topic because "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment."

Is it correct that each question must explicitly say it's used in a business environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don’t need to explicitly mention a business environment.

Please be aware that the Stack Exchange software only allows for a limited number of pre-defined close reasons.

> Questions on Server Fault must be about **managing information technology systems in a business environment.** Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on *Super User*, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on *Stack Overflow*.”

In addition to the obvious we  frequently also use that for a myriad of reasons on questions  that seem quite naive, lack a certain professional understanding of a protocol and technology, or on questions where the other close reasons are not suitable either.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you think I can revise my question to be on-topic, or is it naive in nature? I admit I didn't study networking well at school..

Comment: I still think that what you observe is mainly the background noise of  the internet, where a steady stream of ports cans and login attempts is the norm rather than the exception and nothing to really worry about.  And I can understand that the community would think that the core of your question *"has my server been hacked when my SSH server rejects and terminates invalid connections"* is a *somewhat* naive question.